# In SCSS, how to import partial inside partial

Tags: css, sass

I am beginner in Sass. Please give me the solution.

Here is my folder structure:

```
-> css
    --> main.css

-> sass
    --> partials
          ---> normalize
                ----> _import-now.scss
                ----> _normalize-mixin.scss
                ----> _variables.scss
                ----> _vertical-rhythm.scss
          ---> _normalize.scss
    --> main.scss
```

I've import `_import-now.scss`, `_normalize-mixin.scss`, `_variables.scss` and `_vertical-rhythm.scss` in `_normalize.scss`, then I import `_normalize.scss` in `main.scss`. I didn't get any error but in my `main.css` file doesn't compile any css.

Can anyone help me. I am sorry for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the full paths in your import statements.

e.g.

```
@import 'normalize/_import-now.scss';
@import 'normalize/_normalize-mixin.scss';
@import 'normalize/_variables.scss';
@import 'normalize/_vertical-rhythm.scss';
```

in your `normalize.scss` file, and:

```
@import 'partials/_normalize.scss';
```

in your `main.scss`

Comment: Thank @Starscream for your answer. 

I've import in both way "@import 'normalize/_import-now.scss';" and "@import 'partials/normalize/_import-now.scss';".
And also in main.scss "@import 'partials/_normalize.scss';".

Comment: hmmm, what compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using "Koala"